# Jenkins with Gitlab: Error fetching repo origin

Tags: git, nginx, jenkins, proxy, gitlab

Environment:

Both Jenkins and GitLab are loaded on Nginx. They are accessed via proxy, with different ports each (i.e. Jenkins is accessessible via jenkins.mysite.com and GitLab via gitlab.mysite.com). This is configured in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/vhost`. I also set the HTTP proxy configuration at `Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Advanced -> HTTP proxy configuration` to the following.

`Server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

`Port: 8084 (GitLab)`

While I managed to have a successful connection with Gitlab on the Jenkins server, I keep failing to connect to the GitLab repository.

I found that the connection to the GitLab was successful through this way.

`Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> System Configuration -> Gitlab -> entering the Gitlab host URL and Credentials and then click 'Test Connection' -> Success`

After that I created a new item to see if Jenkins is successfully working with the Gitlab repository. After getting everything equipped, I ran the build and I got the following result.

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Skeleton
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url http://jenkins@gitlab.mysite.com:8084/Web-API-Skeleton/Foo-Api-Skeleton.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://jenkins@gitlab.mysite.com:8084/Web-API-Skeleton/Foo-Api-Skeleton.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
Setting http proxy: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8084
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress http://jenkins@gitlab.mysite.com:8084/Web-API-Skeleton/Foo-Api-Skeleton.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from http://jenkins@gitlab.mysite.com:8084/Web-API-Skeleton/Foodtechkorea-Api-Skeleton.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:812)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1079)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1110)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1276)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:560)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:485)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress http://jenkins@gitlab.mysite.com:8084/Web-API-Skeleton/Foo-Api-Skeleton.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'http://jenkins@gitlab.mysite.com:8084/Web-API-Skeleton/Foo-Api-Skeleton.git/': The requested URL returned error: 400

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1903)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1622)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:348)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:810)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: You have solved this?

Comment: @Zaknafein I somehow managed to solve, but I cannot remember how..